# '[App.framework] Linked and embedded framework 'App.framework' Xcode 11.4 other ways solved problems?

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a flutter project, but recently I upgrade XCode to version 11.4 and I meet this error when switched from IOS simulator to real devices:

- [App.framework] Linked and embedded framework 'App.framework' was built for iOS/iOS Simulator

Here what I have tried :

1. I followed the official integration in website **https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration** and it didn't help at all. It became a nightmare
2. I run **'flutter clean'** after a while on Google and StackOverflow, but it's also not helping much
3. I tried  **'rm -rf ios/Flutter/App.framework'** and rebuild the project and the same error appeared
4. Finally, I found a temporary way to resolve issues that I will copy the IOS folder to another location and regenerate the flutter project again by running following command: **'flutter create .'** and it worked, but this is very inconvenient for me every time I want to switch from the simulator to the real devices.

---

I hope anyone can help me with a better solution for these errors because it's very annoying when doing the debug to the release. Thank you.
By the way, this is my log when running on flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E266, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at /Users/devs/SDK/flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (9 days ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/devs/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.4, Build version 11E146
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.44.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.9.1

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank Google, the new update of Flutter 1.17 fixed this problem, I can build and run the app without the split folder, hope this can help you who meeting this